# Find sum of engagement_time_msec for users who have done an event named "yt_event" in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My table looks like this:

[image]

There's one more column named "user_pseudo_id" which is unique id for users. I want to take sum of event_params.key = 'engagement_time_msec' for user_pseudo_id who have done event_name = 'yt_event'.

Also, event_params.key = 'engagement_time_msec' is only present in two events only, i.e. event_name = 'user_engagement' and 'screen_view'.

I have tried subqueries like this:

```
SELECT
user_pseudo_id,
(
select
sum(value.int_value/60000)
from unnest(event_params)
where
key = 'engagement_time_msec'
and
user_pseudo_id = 'yt_users') as eng_time_min
FROM
  `Xyz.events_20201030`
where
event_name = 'yt_event'
```

But I am not able to get it.

Please help me. I will be highly obliged.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select user_pseudo_id,
  sum(( select value.int_value/60000
    from t.event_params
    where key = 'engagement_time_msec'
  )) as eng_time_min
from `Xyz.events_20201030` t
where user_pseudo_id in (
  select distinct user_pseudo_id
  from `Xyz.events_20201030`
  where event_name = 'yt_event'
)
group by user_pseudo_id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried the code. But the column 'eng_time_min' is showing null values. However the user_pseudo_id are coming correctly.

Comment: i tested above with dummy data resembling your image in question and it perfectly works. provide sample of data in text so we can "troubleshoot" it!

Comment: Hi thanks again. Actually in my data, key engagement_time_msec is only available for 2 events, i.e., user_engagement and screen_view. Since, there's no engagement_time_msec in event_name = 'yt_event', it might me showing null. 

I am unable to provide the data. Not sure how to send you the sample data.

Comment: so change `event_name = 'yt_event'` to `event_name in ('user_engagement', 'screen_view')`

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me sum of engagement_time_msec for all the users. But I want to find the sum of engagement_time_msec for only those users who had done event_name = 'yt_event'. 
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224002/discussion-between-shantanu-jain-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Comment: oh, I see - definitely your original question was not clear enough - ok. will see again when time allow

Comment: Thank @Mikhail. Looking to hear back from you soon.

Comment: Thanks a ton sir! You just saved my day :) I am highly grateful to you. Thanks again. Upvoted and accepted the answer <3

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select user_pseudo_id,
       sum(case when key ep.key = 'engagement_time_msec' then ep.int_val / 60000) as etm
from `Xyz.events_20201030` e cross join
     unnest(event_params) ep
where ep.key in ( 'engagement_time_msec')
group by 1
having countif(event_name = 'yt_event') > 0;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I am actually getting an error msg: 'Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "ep"'. Can you please modify the code..thanks.

Comment: Also, in the last line "countif(ep.key = 'yt_event')", I think it will be event_name = 'yt_event', right?

Comment: @ShantanuJain . . . `ep` is defined by the `unnest()`.